# looping through multiple folders to clear items in each folder

Tags: python, loops, operating-system

I have a folder that contains a lot of subfolders, with images saved as png in each folder :

For example :

```
emotion\angry
emotion\disgusted
emotion\fearful
emotion\happy
```

I can remove the images in one of the folder using the below code :

```
folder_path = (r'C:\Users\emotion\angry')
test = os.listdir(folder_path)
for images in test:
    if images.endswith(".png"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(folder_path, images))
```

How do I create a loop to loop through each subfolder in emotion/?
As I do not want to manually write out all the code to clear all the folders...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can list files using `glob` patterns and delete them using your normal `os.remove`.

```
import os
import glob

fileList = glob.glob('C:\Users\emotion\*\*.png')

for filePath in fileList:
    try:
        os.remove(filePath)
    except:
        print("Error while deleting file : ", filePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def all_dirs(directory):
        # Returning list with all directories in selected directory
        dir_list = []
        for dir in [x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]:
            dir_list.append(dir)
        return dir_list
```

This solution should work for every OS.